# Best way to link datastore entity to its blobstore image?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

Let's say I have a model for my email address book:

```
class contact(db.Model):
    email = db.EmailProperty()
    image = #Hmm.
```

My contacts' images will be stored in the Blobstore, and served at various sizes.

So, should I use a `db.ReferenceProperty(BlobInfo)` such that I can serve it by doing:

```
get_serving_url(alice.image.key, size=x)
```

Or should I use a `db.StringProperty` so that I don't have to make the second read in order to get the key:

```
get_serving_url(alice.image, size=x)
```

Or should I use a `db.LinkProperty` for the base URL, post-fixing the size needed:

```
alice.image+'=sx'
```

---

I don't *foresee* needing anything other than the key, so I think the second is better than the first.

Though I am unsure if the third is *best* because I am unsure whether it is as efficient as creating a unique URL, which can be cached to avoid repeatedly generating the same thumbnail - or is this handled automagically in both cases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362001/store-photos-in-blobstore-or-as-blobs-in-datastore-which-is-better-more-effici  could be an interesting thing to look at.  if you are SURE your blobs won't have > 1Mb and you're not really looking at cost, would be simpler to save them in the datastore.  If you look at cost or have > 1Mb blobs.... blobstore is needed

Comment: @Julldar I'm not comparing where to store my blobs - I'm asking how best to reference my *Blobstore* blob from a *Datastore* entity.

Comment: then in that case, yeah 2nd > 1st, simply because you cut one get, so you have less calls, cheaper and faster results... for the 3rd.... might need a google engineer to weigh-in, I don't know how they magically handle some of these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I think I can answer my own question.

Well, sort of. It turns out that the answer is "this wasn't a real problem to begin with".

While `get_serving_url()` gives the impression that something fancy is being done, actually the 'serving URL' is nothing more than a post-fixing of the supplied `BlobKey`.

What's more, supplying `size=x` merely appends `=sx` - there's nothing special, more or less efficient, about doing it this way. My second and third options, really are identical.

Finally, the `__BlobInfo__` entity kind uses the `BlobKey` as its key name, so it is also easy to access from the other.

---

I have decided to use, and would suggest to anyone with the same dilemma, my third option:

```
imgBlob = db.LinkProperty()
```

It is then easy to:

- append any resizing/cropping requirements
- give a default value/make required without overloading `put()`